# Bind Maven Dependencies to Particular Repositories

Tags: maven-3

In one of our larger projects we already have half a dozen or so remote repositories to collect the various dependencies. When a new repository comes along, Maven tries to download everything from the new repository, there might be a new version after all. Some of these repositories are very slow or don't answer until a timeout, leading to ridiculously long build times.

Another problem is that Maven tries to download our own internal artifacts from remote repositories where they are of course not hosted. I think this is a huge privacy concern.

**Is it possible to configure Maven in such a way that it downloads dependencies only from particular repositories?**

I know that you can setup your own Maven repository manager (like Nexus) but I want to know if it's possible with plain Maven. Trying to fetch local artifacts from remote repositories is annoying even if it's only a little home project that IMHO doesn't warrant setting up a full blown repository manager.

Comment: Are you using a repository manager ? If not start with it. It will exactly against such problems.

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't know what to say to that besides what is contained in the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: The simple problem you have is that you can't control how Maven will access the repositories and in which order. In Nexus you can do that. That's the reason to use a repository manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not keep this question unanswered forever:

**No, it isn't possible.** I think it's a major shortcoming of Maven (one of the many) but there you go.